# Is there a possibility to subset a linear regression model by its studentized residuals?

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to calculate a linear regression model. Since my dataset contains some outliers, I want to delete observations with studentized residuals in excess of two.

Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Best regards